# changing global variable value neovim

Tags: lua, neovim

I am trying to define a custom lua configuration for the nvim-qt GUI. In order to do so, I would first like to toggle fullscreen on and off, but I encounter some pretty weird behavior.

```
vim.g.nvim_qt = {
    fullscreen = false,
    fontsize = 14,
    font_name = 'Iosevka\\ NF:h'
}

local toggle_fullscreen = function ()
    vim.g.nvim_qt.fullscreen = not vim.g.nvim_qt.fullscreen

    if vim.g.nvim_qt.fullscreen then
        return '1'
    else
        return '0'
    end
end

--vim.cmd('call GuiWindowFullScreen(' .. toggle_fullscreen() ..')')
vim.keymap.set('n', '<F11>', ':call GuiWindowFullScreen(' .. toggle_fullscreen() ..')<CR>')
```

What I would expect, is the value of fullscreen to be toggled on each function call. It however always remains false. Can anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% familiar with the Neovim-qt framework, but your toggle_fullscreen() function does seems to work fine. When running this locally, I get the toggling behavior.

Could you provide some more information how the keymap exactly works? My guess is that the set() function simple runs the toggle_fullscreen once and saves it in the keymap as ":call GuiWindowFullScreen(0)", which leads you to always calling the function with a false value.

Comment: oh my god, you are right. I marked it as answered because that is exactly what is happening. can't believe I missed this, as it is quite obvious. thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into trouble with the following code:

```lua
function toggle(key)
  vim.g.my_map[key] = not vim.g.my_map[key]
end
```

The global variable wasn't updating.  The docs were great though, they explained it clearly (`:h lua-vim-variables`)

```
Note that setting dictionary fields directly will not write them back into
Nvim. This is because the index into the namespace simply returns a copy.
Instead the whole dictionary must be written as one. This can be achieved by
creating a short-lived temporary.

Example:

    vim.g.my_dict.field1 = 'value'  -- Does not work

    local my_dict = vim.g.my_dict   --
    my_dict.field1 = 'value'        -- Instead do
    vim.g.my_dict = my_dict         --
```

This fixed it:

```lua
function toggle(key)
  local temp = vim.g.my_map[key]
  temp[key] = not vim.g.my_map[key]
  vim.g.my_map = temp
end
```